# Regex that excludes invalid escapes in a Java string

Tags: java, regex, regex-lookarounds

I've been stuck on this for days and I just can't figure it out. I'm trying to write a regex for double-quoted string literals that supports escape characters. The regex should accept a string such as `"1\t2"` (\"1\\t2\") and reject a string such as `"invalid\escape"` (\"invalid\\escape\"). This will handle valid and invalid escapes, `\"(\\(?=[bnrt\'\"\\]).)*\"` but as soon as I introduce anything to handle a string it just accepts everything (i.e., `^\"(.*(\\(?=[bnrt\\\'\"]))*)*\"$`. I'm pretty sure the issue is that when it loops back around and the preceding character is `\\` (\\\\) it allows any character to be placed after it. I just cannot figure it out. I've deleted my work and started from scratch more times than I can remember, I've gone to office hours twice, and I just cannot figure it out. I need fresh eyes on this because I'm blind to it and at my wits end. I'm not looking to be given the answer. I just want help figuring out what I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Your string regex starts with `.*` after the opening quote. This matches any string, regardless of its content. You follow it with `(<escape_regex>)*`, but since a `*` also allows zero matches, the regex engine just ignores it. In other words, your string regex is equivalent to `^\".*\"$`.

To change this behaviour, you have to ensure that a backslash can only match if it is also followed by a valid character. This can be done by changing your dot with `[^\\]`, which matches every character but a backslash. The resulting regex looks like this and works on your given samples: `^\"([^\\]*(\\(?=[bnrt\'\"\\]).)*)*\"$`.

There is, however, a much simpler approach. `([^\\]|\\[bnrt\'\"\\])` matches either a non-backslash character, or a backslash followed by a valid escape character. Do that n times and you have a string filled with only valid escape characters: `^\"([^\\]|\\[bnrt\'\"\\])*\"$`. This regex also works on your samples, and will perform a lot better, as your suggested regex suffers from [catastrophic backtracking](https://www.regular-expressions.info/catastrophic.html).

Comment: Thanks for the response. I’m not sure what happened but I thought I answered my question that 1-2 hrs after the initial posting because I figured it out. I actually figured out the same solution you mentioned. Maybe I was only reviewing my post and I still needed to actually post it? Either way, I really your response. This one had me so frustrated.